# Unable to fill PDF fields when FDF contains Kids sections FPDF/FPDM

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, pdftk

I can successfully fill PDF forms,but it looks to be breaking when there are Kids sections in them.

E.g. this is the file I'm working with:

```
$ pdftk test.pdf dump_data_fields | grep FieldName
FieldName: Text36.0
FieldName: Text36.1
FieldName: Text37.1
FieldName: Text37.0.0
FieldName: Text37.0.1.0
FieldName: Text37.0.1.1
FieldName: Text38
FieldName: Text39.0
...
FieldName: Text41.5.23.1.19.5
FieldName: Text41.5.23.1.19.6
FieldName: Text41.5.23.1.19.7
FieldName: Text41

$ pdftk test.pdf dump_data_fields | grep FieldName | wc -l
402
```

This works:

```
<?php
require_once 'fpdm-2.9.2/fpdm.php';
$fields = [
    'Text38' => 'Joe'
];
$pdf = new FPDM('test.pdf', 'test.fdf', true);
$pdf->Load($fields);
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output('F', 'test_out.pdf');
```

Output:

```
PDF parse

Starting to parse 14336 entries

PDF parse retrieved 1094 refs

Merge info:

26 Field entry values found for 1 field values to fill

Output

Write file test_out.pdf
```

This does not (same code as above, only different field name):

```
$fields = [
    'Text36.0' => 'Joe'
];

FPDF-Merge Error: field Text36.0 not found
```

Snip from the FDF file:

```
/T (Text41)
>> 
<<
/Kids [
<<
/V ()
/T (1)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (0)
>>]
/T (Text36)
>> 
<<
/Kids [
<<
/V ()
/T (1)
>> 
<<
/Kids [
<<
/Kids [
<<
/V ()
/T (1)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (0)
>>]
/T (1)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (0)
>>]
/T (0)
>>]
/T (Text37)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (Text38)
>> 
<<
/Kids [
<<
/V ()
/T (19)
>> 
<<
/V ()
/T (18)
>>
```

So I'm trying to figure out if I'm sending the wrong data in, or if this is a limitation of the FPDM library.

Comment: Note that I originally tried this without the FPF: `$pdf = new FPDM('test.pdf');` but to get verbose mode turned on, it appears the library requires the second argument. It behaves identically in either case.

Comment: This is a limitation of FPDM.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @Olivier. Guess it's back to the drawing board.